# Is there a way in python to use the property decorator with pygame's rect data type?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to give a custom class a rect attribute by using the `@property` decorator to return a new rect object with the object's x, y, width and height.

```python
@property
  def rect(self):
    return pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
  
  @rect.setter
  def rect(self, new_rect):
    self.x = new_rect.x
    self.y = new_rect.y
    self.width = new_rect.width
    self.height = new_rect.height
```

I can make a setter to completely replace the rect with a new rect, updating the object's attributes appropriately, but is there a way to make it work whenever the attributes of the rect are updated (ie `object.rect.bottomright = [5, 3]` will create the rect, update the attribute bottomright and apply the changes to the object's x, y, width and height)? If there's a better approach I'm missing, that would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Not unless you return some kind of wrapper from `object.rect` that proxies any interactions back to the `object`.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What's wrong with a `rect` attribute?

Comment: Why are you storing x, y, width, and height separately? You could just have a rect attribute on your object and modify it, like normal.

Comment: Thanks, I was avoiding having a `rect` attribute contain the `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` because I didn't want to have to access the `rect` attribute any time I wanted to access one of those common attributes, but I realized that I could simply subclass the `pygame.Rect` class to get this effect with all of the resulting attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was avoiding having a `rect` attribute contain the `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`  because I didn't want to have to access the `rect` attribute any time I wanted to access one of those common attributes, but I realized that I could simply subclass the `pygame.Rect` class to get this effect with all of the resulting attributes.